# How do you parameterize deployments when using ASP.NET 4.5 publish profiles?

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy, asp.net-4.5

The new pubxml files in ASP.NET 4.5 are definitely a step in the right direction.
I also like `msdeploy`'s support for `parameters.xml` files (even though they are sometimes not as powerful as I would like). Now, how do I combine `msdeploy`'s parameters and the pubxml files?
I would expect that the pubxml files would allow me to provide a setting like

`<ParametersFile>productionParameters.xml</ParametersFile>`

or something similar in my `production.pubxml` file, that would contain values to be merged into `web.config` when publishing to the production environment. Is that possible or do I have to go back to rolling my own way of determining the parameters file and invoking `msdeploy` with -setParamFile="productionParameters.xml"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't set your own parameters file, but you can declare parameter values from within the `pubxml`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MSDeployParameterValue Include="Parameter Name">
    <ParameterValue>Parameter Value</ParameterValue>
  </MSDeployParameterValue>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Sorry, I don't quite follow. If I declare a parameter like that, what happens - are they only used by the publishing wizard or can I have them merged into web.config? After being declared here, where are they actually used?

Comment: The above syntax _is_ the assignment and is different for each Publish Profile. If you need to declare additional parameters (beyond the auto-generated parameters for connection strings and IIS Application), you can either define them in `wpp.targets` with `<MsDeployDeclareParameters>` or add a `Parameters.xml` to the root of your web application and anything defined in there will be merged with the auto-generated ones.

Comment: This technique doesn't seem to override defaults set in Parameters.xml.  I had to redeclare the parameters, with defaults, with a priority that superseded Parameters.xml as described [here](http://sedodream.com/2013/03/02/MSDeployHowToUpdateAppSettingsOnPublishBasedOnThePublishProfile.aspx).