# How to override ASP.NET deployment parameters when publishing

Tags: asp.net, deployment, msbuild, msdeploy, web-publishing

I've seen some questions, read all the posts, still I can't get this done. Either I'm missing something, or it cannot be done..

So I have a rather simple (ASP.NET MVC) project.
In the root of my project there is a parameters.xml file with parameter definitions, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
  <parameter 
   name="Realm"
   description="Realm for ADFS authentication"
   defaultValue="http://somewebsite">
   <parameterEntry 
      kind="XmlFile"
      scope="Web.config"
      match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ida:Realm']/@value" />
   <parameterEntry 
      kind="XmlFile" 
      scope="Web.config"
      match="/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/audienceUris/add/@value" />
<parameterEntry 
      kind="XmlFile" 
      scope="Web.config"
      match="/configuration/system.identityModel.services/federationConfiguration/wsFederation/@realm" />
```

So far so good. This structure is very well understood, you a name of a deployment parameter (e.g. "Realm") a default value for it, and a few XCLT options where it can be found in the Web.config file.

Now when I create a deployment package, by running Publish, I get a directory that contains:

1. An auto generated cmd file for the deployment
2. A readme file
3. A manifest XML file
4. A zip file with all the files that have to be deployed to my server.
5. A .SetParameters.xml file

That last file contains the parameter values which were set in the parameters.xml file I quoted above, and those values are set to be the default ones which were defined there.
e.g. if the default value for Realm was set to be http://somewebsite, in the generated deployment SetParameters.xml, I will get this record:

```
<setParameter name="Realm" value="http://somewebsite" />
```

When the package gets deployed, these values will be taken from this xml file and replace the values in my Web.Config, according to the XPaths defined in the original parameter.xml file.

Now, what I want is to override this parameters (as well as many others) when I build my deployment package, because I need different values for different deployment profiles.

The key seems to be my .pubxml file, which is in charge of the publishing settings. I tried many options, including what Sayed Hashimi said [here](http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,25ddd39e-59de-4e35-becc-de19dcc5e4ea.aspx), previous answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030265/how-do-you-parameterize-deployments-when-using-asp-net-4-5-publish-profiles) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890323/web-config-transformation-msdeploy-keeping-production-passwords-out-of-sourc), [here too](http://cromwellhaus.com/2012/05/build-once-msdeploy-all-over-the-place/) (and others too)... nothing seems to make a difference for the damn parameters!

Am I missing something? Is there some magic hack?
Should I ignore the params altogether and just rely on a matching web.config transformation? Any other advice? Maybe add custom targets to the .csproj file? (even tried that...)

Thank you!
Alon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDeploy Parameterization occurs at deploy time not build time (like config transforms).  We use Parameterization for 50+ products at work with great success.  For each product we have 4 SetParameters files:

- SetParameters.DEV.xml
- SetParameters.QA.xml
- SetParameters.UAT.xml
- SetParameters.PROD.xml

Each has the parameter values which are valid for its environment.  We use a PowerShell script and Thoughtworks GO to execute the MSDeploy the package in a pipeline with the appropriate SetParameters file.

One note, make sure to not deploy your SetParameters files with your application - http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/04/02/webdeploy-parameterization-tip-dont-publish-your-parameterization-files/

Also, if you want to preview your parameterization in VS this may be helpful - http://dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: Thanks @chief7! I am trying to reduce the work and automate the process using existing tools.
It seems to me there is no way to bind a set of param values to a publishing profile (unless I add some manual labor outside msdeploy/build).
The only workaround so far: creating a web.config transformation that matches the publishing profile name. This doesn't change web.config during build but only in the produced deployment package. It's also more powerful, since I can make actual changes to the config according to the deployment environment (e.g. different ConfigSections for different auth modes).

Comment: If you wish to deploy via the build process, config transforms are you best bet.  Note however this will require you to build for each environment deployment which raises the risk that someone will checkin a new change between builds and introduce untested code to an upper environment.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again, @chief7.
BTW, since you seem to be more experienced in this than I am, suppose I want to override the SetParameters.xml file in the deployment folder (next to the deploy cmd file) with the content of SetParameters.DEV.xml (so those values get applied during deployment), you mention a PowerShell script, is this how you copy/apply/run that? Can it be somehow automated from the .pubxml file when the deployment package is produced?
I just find it really strange that overriding the "default values" in the parameters.xml file per publishing profile has to be done somehow manually...

Comment: I looked but couldn't find a way to override the SetParameters file when using a publish profile.  Publish profiles are just an extension of MSBuild.  Outside of the MSBuild process, we use PowerShell scripts to call MSDeploy.exe and deploy a package with a custom SetParameters.[env].xml.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that much. Just thought you might have a useful hack that doesn't include custom scripts or 3rd party tools. Thank you very much, @chief7! I accepted your comment as an answer, even though I didn't fully get what I wanted, but you were very helpful with info. Thanks again.

Comment: I still can't get this to work for me. I see msdeploy running from my TFS task, but the transform doesn't happen on my web.config in Azure. Is there any way to see output of the transform? Line 10,007 of my log here: https://gist.github.com/mrichman/eca654ff4db614e9941fc2c1ab577a99

Comment: @Mark - It looks like your passing the parameters.xml file to the -setParamFile argument instead of the SetParameters.[env].xml file.

Comment: I got it working. Was missing the /@value from my xpath